# vba code to paste value in open workbooks which have similar name to a range value

Tags: vba, excel

I got stuck in the below-mentioned code, what I want to do is to get the value from `Range("C4:C" & LastRow)` in worksheets X2 that will b changing every time and compare each value with all open workbooks name. If match found then search that value in A column of worksheet X1 and copy all those rows.

The final objective is to paste those rows into those open workbooks which have the same value. For eg: Range C4 has TW00 then the code will search workbooks which have name "TW00.xlsx" and copy all the rows from worksheet X1 which have TW00 value in column A in the worksheet named TW00.xlsx.

```
Dim BookNames()
ReDim BookNames(Windows.Count)
n = 1

For n = 1 To Windows.Count
    BookNames(n) = Workbooks(n).Name
    If Workbooks(n).Name = Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("X2").Range("C4:C" & LastRow).Value Then
        Set Rng = Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("X1").Range("A2:A50000")
        For Each c In Rng.Cells
            If c.Value = Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("X2").Range("C4").Value Then
                If Not CopyRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set CopyRng = Application.Union(CopyRng, 
                    Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("X1").Rows(c))
                Else
                    Set CopyRng = Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("X1").Rows(c)
                End If
            End If
        Next c

        CopyRng.Copy
        Workbooks(n).Activate
        Worksheets.Add
        ActiveSheet.Name = "X1"
        ActiveSheet.Paste

    End If
Next n
```

Comment: Do You need add new worksheet every time data copied?

Comment: do you mean that the open workbooks have worksheets by the same name? Seems like you are adding a sheet called X1 to workbooks and pasting there.

Comment: Not every time, The New worksheet is not added to "A.xlsx" workbook but new worksheet is being added in those open workbooks which are having the same name as Range("C4").

Comment: put the last row value into a variable and then loop the open workbooks doing your comparison. Then an inner loop, if match, that gathers your union range and pastes across into newly added sheet (or existing if specified)

Comment: no, I want to match against open workbooks name, not worksheet name.

Comment: Do your workbooks have different extensions? As you say "The final objective is to paste those rows into those open workbooks which are having the same value" so my guess it you would have to have workbooks with the same name but different extensions.

Comment: for avoiding such confusions I can change the worksheet names from X1 to X3. Refer the edit code

Comment: i know that your are matching on workbook name but you say the following:  "column A in the worksheet named TW00.xlsx. "

Comment: No extensions are same .xlsx

Comment: @QHrr column A in the worksheet X1 that is static

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162180/discussion-between-yashika-vaish-and-qharr).

Answer (score 0):

is that code help you?

```
Sub test()
Dim lastRow As Long
dim sheetName as string
Dim sourceDataSheet As worksheet
Dim sourceSheetsName as worksheet
dim targetDataSheet as worksheet
Dim wkb As Variant

set sourceDataSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("X2")
set sourceSheetsName  = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("X1")

With sourceSheetsName  
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    sheetName = .Cells(lastRow, "A")
        For Each wkb In Application.Workbooks
            If wkb.Name <> .Name And wkb.Name = sheetName Then
                set targetDataSheet = wkb.Worksheets.Add
                with sourceDataSheet
                    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    for i = 1 to lastRow
                        if .Cells(i, "A").Value = sheetName then
                            .Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Copy
                            targetDataSheet.Cells(i, "A").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                        end if
                    next i
                end with
            End If
        Next wkb
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank u :) This code pastes the value into the correct sheet but the value I want to paste is all the rows of matching value from X1 worksheet but above code paste values from X2 worksheets A column cell values.

Comment: please switch the names in code for `sourceDataSheet` and `sourceSheetsName`

Comment: I have done the same but it could not be able to copy complete rows from worsheet x

Comment: It gives me all rows , but I want only those rows which a column value is similar to workbook name in which it is to be copied

Comment: Consider still using Union (as OP did initially) and pasting the Union range once at the end. Far more efficient.

Comment: With sourceSheetsName
                    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
                    If Cells(i, "A").Value = wkb.Name Then
                 If Not CopyRng Is Nothing Then
                Set CopyRng = Application.Union(CopyRng, Rows(i))
           Else
                Set CopyRng = Rows(i)
           End If
           CopyRng.Copy
           targetDataSheet.Paste     I have updated the above code like this but no value is being pasted.